# Find all triangles with a fixed base and opposite angle

Tags: triangles

I have a situation where I know the cartesian coordinates of the 2 vertices of a triangle that form its base, hence I know the length of the base and this is fixed.

I also know the angle opposite the base and this is also fixed.

Now what I want to do is figure out how to compute all possible positions for the third vertex.

My maths is rusty, I reverted to drawing lots of pictures and with the help of some tracing paper I believe that the set of all possible vertices that satisfies the fixed base and opposite angle prescribes a circle or possibly some sort of ellipse, my drawings are too rough to discern which.

I started with a simple case of an equilateral triangle, with a base length of two, i.e. the 3rd vertex is directly above the x origin, 0, base runs from -1 to 1 along the x-axis

then i started drawing other triangles that had that same base, -1 to 1 and the same opposite angle of 60 degrees or pi/3 depending on your taste

now i need to take it to the next step and compute the x and y coordinates for all possible positions of that opposite vertex.

struggling with the maths, do i use the sin rule, i.e. sin a / A = sin b/ B and so on, or do I need to break it down into right angle triangles and then just use something along the lines of a^2 + b^2 = c^2

ultimately, I intend to plot the line that represents all the possible vertex positions but i have to figure out the mathematical relationship between that and the facts, namely,

```
base is fixed running from (-1,0) to (1,0)
angle opposite the base is 60 deg
```

I then need to extend to arbitrary bases and opposite angles, but thought starting with a nice simple one might be a good stepping stone.

apologies if my formatting is poor - first post on math stack exchange - i am more a stack overflow sort of guy..

Comment: The locus of the vertex is a part circle, due to the theorem " angles in the same segment are equal"

Comment: If the angle opposite is $\pi\over 2$, you have a semi-circle; you can compare the behavior of other angles to this based on whether they are greater or less than $\pi\over 2$...

Comment: @David - brilliant - i think that is the fact that will allow me to solve my problem, and certainly give me the necessary search term for a whole load of relevant googling - happy to accept this as the answer if you want to present it as one.

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locus of the vertex is a part circle, due to the theorem " angles in the same segment are equal"

Comment: That's not true.

Answer (score 2):

A general solution to the problem:

Let the triangle have sides $a,b,c$ and angles opposite to these sides as $A,B,C$ respectively. We fix $a$ between points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. For a fixed $A$, we need to find the mathematical equation of the locus of third point, $(x_3,y_3)$.

Using sine rule, we have:
$$
\frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B} = \frac{c}{\sin C} = k
$$
where $k$ is easily found since we know $a$ and $A$.

In the triangle, angle $C = 180 - (B+A)$. We also see that:
$$
b = k \cdot \sin B
$$
Similarly,
$$
c = k \cdot \sin (180-(B+A)) = k \cdot \sin (B+A) 
$$
For different values of $B$, we will have corresponding values of $b$ and $c$. Knowing $a,b,c$ fixes the triangle.

From basic geometry, we have: $b= \sqrt{(x_3-x_2)^2+(y_3-y_2)^2}$ and $c= \sqrt{(x_3-x_1)^2+(y_3-y_1)^2}$.

The locus of $(x_3,y_3)$ is given by simultaneously solving:
$$
(x_3-x_1)^2+(y_3-y_1)^2 = k^2 \cdot \sin ^2 (B+A)
$$
$$
(x_3-x_2)^2+(y_3-y_2)^2 = k^2 \cdot \sin ^2 (B)
$$
when $B$ varies from $0$ to $(180-A)$ degrees. The locus will be the arc of the circle. The base $a$ serves as a chord.

Comment: very elegant algebraic manipulation - i had initially ventured down this route but not got so far - thanks for filling in the gaps although i will have to refresh my knowledge on solving simultaneous equations. I think this compliments the more geometric approach of using central angle theorem and same angles for a given segment very nicely

Comment: also how do you format the maths so nicely - is there someway i can see the markup you used?

Comment: @bph I am not sure how to send you the markup for the above answer, as stackexchange doesn't allow messages. 
Have a look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help to help you understand the formatting. The equations are written using the same markup as one would use in LaTeX. Math Stackexchange uses https://www.mathjax.org/ 
The LaTeX syntax for math is not too hard I would say - should take you an hour or so to get the basics and anything else that you need you would be able to look it up online! :)

Comment: thanks i was just looking up some simliar links myself - i wondered if it were latex based..

Comment: @bph Just realized that you can see the markup for my answer by clicking on edit, just below it.

Comment: i'll practice on my answer below

Comment: that mathjax.org documentation is a bit inpenetrable.. hopefully a simple beginners intro exists somewhere - editing your answer to see the markup was invaluable..

Comment: @bph: Another way to see the markup is to highlight the equation and then right-click on it. A context menu should pop up. Select "Show Math As > TeX commands"

Answer (score 2):

Vertices of the triangles sought form two circle's arcs.

See [Inscribed angle — Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fleshing out of my geometric approach, inspired by David Quinn's input utilising the 'angles for the same segment are equal' theorem and the 'central angle theorem'

[image]

for case where chord is horizontal (parallel to x-axis)

(and any chord can be made to be parallel by rotating the circle appropriately)

$$
a = \frac{x_2-x_1}{2}
$$
$$
r = \frac{a}{\sin(\theta)} 
$$
$$
r = \frac{\left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{2}\right)}{\sin(\theta)}
$$
$$
b = \frac{a}{\tan(\theta)}
$$
$$
b = \frac{\left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{2}\right)}{\tan(\theta)}
$$
therefore if the origin, $o$ has cartesian coordinates $[o_x,o_y]$
$$
o_x = x_1 + \frac{x_2-x_1}{2}
$$
$$
o_x = \frac{x_1+x2}{2}
$$
$$
o_y = y_1 + \frac{\left(\frac{x_1+x2}{2}\right)}{\tan(\theta)}
$$
so we know the origin, $[o_x,o_y]$ and radius, $r$, of the circle prescribing the locus of all solutions

so if we want to convert back from polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates we use the following:

$$
x = r\cos(\phi)
$$
$$
y = r\sin(\phi)
$$
$\phi$ is the angle as we travel round the circle, $r$ the radius

this assumes the centre of the circle is at the origin so that has to be corrected, e.g.
$$
x = r\cos(\theta) + \frac{x_1+x2}{2}
$$
$$
y = r\sin(\phi) + y_1 + \frac{\left(\frac{x_1+x2}{2}\right)}{\tan(\theta)}
$$

Comment: got there in the end with the latex formatting.. would like to use some square brackets round a \frac though

Comment: As an alternative LaTeX / MathJax reference, you may find the [Wikipedia Help:Displaying a formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula) article useful. However, not everything mentioned in that article will work here.

Comment: thats a really useful link - has enabled me to stick some brackets round fractions, went round rather than square - looks ok!